# Configure release staging with Jenkins, Gradle Artifactory plugin

Tags: jenkins, gradle, artifactory, staging

I have Artifactory (non-Artifactory Pro version!) with Jenkins and its Gradle Artifactory plugin and want to setup release staging.

As I can't choose the release repository (it is disabled) while performing the release I was wondering if this already requires Artifactory Pro?

For the job configuration I see an option Custom staging configuration with only one option: None? What is this Custom staging configuration for and how can I customize this?

Are there other options to setup this efficiently for a project built with Gradle. As of now I have tried to delegate as much as possible to Jenkins and its Plugins.

Answer (score 2):

[Artifactory release management](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Release+Management) functionality is only available in Artifactory Pro version.

Custom staging profile feature allows you select a [staging profile user plugin](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins#UserPlugins-Staging), that is deployed in Artifactory (also a Pro feature).

You're more than welcome to try those on an evaluation license. If you find the license price too heavy for you, please take a look at Artifactory SaaS version - it's a fully pledged Pro instance in a cloud, and you only pay per use per month.